# Angular-cli build folder don't structure

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

After angular-cli build dist folder containing files all types together (.html, .js and etc).
Is there a way to create a folder for scripts and put all the js files in it during the build process?

Comment: Running `ng build` will compile your TS files into a single JS file in the `dist` folder. You'll have to switch to something like `systemjs` if you want a individual javascript files for each Typescript file.

Comment: Use `ng eject`, then do what ever you like. [ng eject wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject)

Comment: thx, but it don't help me

Comment: Modify your build configuration in `angular.json` to move the scripts file into separate folder. For more information refer my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299668/angular-9-build-bundle-directory/60375578?noredirect=1#comment106846442_60375578