# Angular 9 Build Bundle Directory

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set up my Angular 9 build to output style and script bundles into a specific subfolder (e.g. "app") and have index.html use those paths in its references to the bundles. I found some old and some conflicting information on this but nothing quite hit the spot yet. The Angular CLI has been updated frequently and significantly, and approaches may have changed. I want to do this within `angular.json`, not with any type of a postbuild script, a CLI flag, etc., so that I can maintain this cleanly within the source code.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You just have to move the files in the folders that you want and change the paths of them in the angular.json file. Same for the tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json files.

Comment: I'm not sure that does it. They are already in the `src/app` folder as well as the project's subfolder where various components resides. In other words, the build performs a collection of all files wherever they may reside in the regular Angular folder structure. What I really need is to be able to redirect the output of that collection to a `dist/<project>/app` folder (above are the contents of `dist/<project>`).

Comment: Modifying `angular.json`'s `projects -> <project> -> architect -> build -> options` to add `"deployUrl": "static/"` gets me halfway there as it modifies `index.html` appropriately:  

`<script src="static/runtime.a24cb8607fbb7fe5cb02.js" defer></script><script src="static/polyfills.da2c6c4849ef9aea9de5.js" defer></script><script src="static/main.e4257867b606d22bb996.js" defer></script></body>`  

However, it does not copy my assets into a `static` folder; they remain in a flat hierarchy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `angular.json` modify the following build configuration it will move the transpiled typescript files to the `static` folder.

```
"outputPath": "dist/<project>/static",
"deployUrl": "static/",
"index": {
    "input": "src/index.html",
    "output": "../index.html"
},
```

[image]

For Assets structuring use the following configuration

```
"assets": [
    {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "src/assets/",
        "output": "./../assets/"
    },
    {
        "glob": "favicon.ico",
        "input": "src/",
        "output": "./../"
    }
],
```

Comment: This is clever and 9/10s there. You deploy everything to the `static` path, then simply copy the `index.html` file, which has updated script and style paths via `deployUrl` one directory up from `static`. I don't think you even need the `assets` code snippet with the object.

The 1/10s that's left that I struggle a bit with is deploying any resources that are directly in `src` to the same location as `index.html`. For example, `favicon.ico` or a custom `login.html` page at `src` should be siblings to `index.html`. Unlike that file, you can't copy assets one directory higher up (e.g. `../`).

Comment: Thank you Simon, you can even copy that as well using the asset object. Try this `"assets": [
                            {
                                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                                "input": "src/",
                                "output": "../"
                            },
                            {
                                "glob": "login.html",
                                "input": "src/",
                                "output": "../"
                            }
                        ],`

Comment: Thank you, Akilesh. I tried that before and then saw this error message that led me to say earlier that you couldn't copy assets one directory higher up (e.g. `../`):


An unhandled exception occurred: An asset cannot be written to a location outside of the output path.

Comment: Yes, for security reasons `angular-cli` restricts the build to copy the assets outside the project output path `dist/<project>/static`.
Out of curiosity, when I took a deeper look into the build options for the assets configurations in `node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\common.js Line No: 191`. I have found that they were validating the path, in case, if any asset output path starts with `(..)`, it will throw an error. Hence adding the current directory`(./)` before the parent directory`(../)` will solve this. (e.g. `"./../assets/"`).

Comment: @AkileshKumarR the bit with the "index" property is magic! I had no idea you could do that. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

I am not positive what the proper etiquette is, but I can't paste all these steps into a comment to an existing answer. All credit for this answer is due to Akilesh Kumar. Without his help, I would not have gotten this to work, so thank you very much. I will be happy to mark your answer as correct for credit if that's the way to do it. For anyone looking at this, this answer may be a bit more focused and "in one place."

---

These steps were performed with Angular CLI 9.0.5. This solution just demonstrates one general way to set this up. You can modify this per configuration, of course, if desired.

1. Run `ng new TestApp`. Accept any defaults, if prompted.
2. Run `ng build` to see the baseline output prior to making any changes. All files are in the same directory.

   [image]
3. Open the TestApp folder in your favorite editor.
4. In *angular.json* -> projects -> TestApp -> architect -> build -> options, add or modify these entries:

   ```
   "deployUrl": "assets/",
   "outputPath": "dist/TestApp/assets",
   "index": {
     "input": "src/index.html",
     "output": "../index.html"
   }, 
   "assets": [
     {
       "glob": "favicon.ico",
       "input": "src/",
       "output": "./../"
     },  
     {
       "glob": "**/*",
       "input": "src/assets/",
       "output": "./"
     }
   ],
   ```
5. Delete the *dist* folder, then run `ng build` to see *index.html* and *favicon.ico* in *dist\TestApp* and all other assets in *dist\TestApp\assets*.

   [image]

   [image]
6. To further show other assets being correctly set up, place a resource into the source assets (e.g. *src\assets\img\kitten.jpg*).
7. Edit *src\index.html* to reference that asset:

   ```
   <body>
     <img src="./assets/img/kitten.jpg">
     <app-root></app-root>
   </body>
   ```
8. Delete the *dist* folder, then run `ng build` to see *dist\TestApp\assets\img\kitten.jpg*.

   [image]
9. Run a local http server out of the *dist* directory to see the image show in the browser.

   [image]

Comment: Simon, thank you very much for describing the procedure. I've following it and got a successful build. However, now "ng serve" doesn't work properly (builds but can't GET). Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi Arsenii, I've not taken this further yet than what's described above. Can you provide more details on the error you see, please?

Comment: When I run ng serve, compilation goes smooth, but then it tells not to open a browser on localhost:4200 but on localhost:4200/assets. Both things are not working (showing "cannot GET"). I've tried several variants to change options of ng serve directly without any success and finally just created additional build configuration "buildForServe" in angular.json that just replicates everything from "build" except using default paths. Not a brilliant solution but it works. Do you have any idea how to change just serve options for it to work without an alternative build creation?

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I haven't pursued that path and, without tinkering with it myself, wouldn't be able to give you any more information. While I use `ng serve` as well, typically, I ran this with just a simple http-server to see how it would behave once placed on a server.

If you have something workable, it would be great if you posted it here, please.